# Create New user in tortoise SVN installed in windows server

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I Installed tortoise SVN in windows server. i want to create different user,  please let me know how to create users, right now i am able to check in check out the code with ADMINSTRATOR. Please let me know how to create users.

Comment: TortoiseSVN is a *client* program, not a *server*. It doesn't belongs to Windows Server and you can't host repositories with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't set up a proper Subversion server, so you can't properly do what you're attempting to do.

You need to install a Subversion server such as CollabNet Subversion Edge, <s>WANDisco's uberSVN,</s> VisualSVN Server, or put it all together yourself with standard Subversion distribution and (if you want to use HTTP) Apache. The [official Subversion manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com) has more details.

Comment: UberSVN is no longer supported and not available anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the replay.. i want to maintain my code with version, could you suggest some open source repositories

Comment: I don't understand that comment.